# Overriding left menu font and position in main style.css file

Tags: css, wordpress

I do not even know how this came to be, but some tabs of my menu on twenty fourteen have an indent. Furthermore, depending on the active tab, the font of the menu varies.
[image]

Multiple programmers went on it, so I suspect that multiple pages (as well as some custome templates) have their own css regarding the menu. Is there a way to uniformize all the tabs for all the pages within the main style sheet. The only code I have related to the menu in the style sheet is the following, which can't explain this behavior. Furthermore, the pages are not set as children page in the menu dashboard.

```html
li#menu-item-1537 a,  li#menu-item-1494 a, li#menu-item-1492 a, li#menu-item-1874 a{
    padding: 10px 20px !important;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.page-id-48 li#menu-item-1537 a, .page-id-48 li#menu-item-1494 a, .page-id-48 li#menu-item-1492 a, .page-id-48 li#menu-item-1874 a{
    padding: 10px 20px !important;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}
```

Comment: Is there a sandbox where this can be viewed or you able to paste what the HTML for the menu looks like? Without seeing the elements, their classes, and the hierarchy it's difficult to provide a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this should be something which you can fix in your Wordpress systems'  Backend, in `Appearance > Menus`.

If it is what I think it is, the indented menu items are defined as submenu items on that page (i.e. also slightly moved to the right here)-  just drag them to the left to line up with the first-level items.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing seems wrong in the menus section, as none of the items appears to be defined as submenu.

Comment: they are all vertically aligned left in the backend?

Comment: Yes, hence why I think there is some css here and there, and I'm wondering if I can override all those css chunks